# Traducir JS a jQuery para añadir una clase css a un botón

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Es la primera vez que trabajo con jQuery y necesito transformar este código JS a jQuery, al que llamo desde un botón en html. La idea es que el botón con id=btnFiltroAvanzado se oculte al pulsarlo y se muestre el botón id=btnSimple, e igual al contrario.

HTML:

```
<p:button id=btnFiltroAvanzado 
onclick="this.classList.add('p-d-none'); 
document.getElementById('btnSimple').classList.remove('p-d-none');"/>

<p:button id=btnSimple
styleClass="p-d-none"
onclick="this.classList.add('p-d-none'); 
document.getElementById('btnFiltroAvanzado ').classList.remove('p-d-none');"/>
```

donde la clase p-d-none es simplemente

```
.p-d-none{
   display: none !important;
}
```

He probado creando la función:

```
function swapVisibility(idHide, idShow) {
    $("#idHide").addClass("p-d-none");
    $("#idShow").removeClass("p-d-none");
    return false;
}

<p:button id=btnFiltroAvanzado 
onclick="swapVisibility('btnFiltroAvanzado', 'btnSimple')">
```

pero no funciona.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Los `id` de los `button` son `btnSimple` y `btnFiltroAvanzado`, pero en jQuery estas usando `idHide` y `idShow`

Comment: jQuery es una **librería de Javascript**. Se puede usar jQuery cuando escribes código javascript, pero no se traduce de JS a jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado el problema.

El error se encontraba en el selector, el script correcto sería:

```
function swapVisibility(idHide, idShow) {
    $("#" + idHide).addClass("p-d-none");
    $("#" + idShow).removeClass("p-d-none");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: En ese caso, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te fue más útil. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [answer] y [ask].

Answer (score 2):

No se en jquery, que no lo he usado nunca, pero con javascript puedes hacerlo. Solo tienes que agregarle una clase a los 2 botones para identificarlos y luego añadir un addEventListener para que añada o quite la clase.

Esto sería el html

```
    <p:button class="btn-filtro">filtro simple</p:button>
    <p:button class="btn-filtro p-d-none">filtro avanzado</p:button>
```

Y esto en la sección de script

```
    const filtros = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-filtro");
    for(let i=0; i<filtros.length; i++){
        filtros[i].addEventListener("click", mostrarOcultar);
    }
    function mostrarOcultar(){
        for(let i=0; i<filtros.length; i++){
            filtros[i].classList.toggle("p-d-none");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una respuesta para que cambies directamente los estilos en la función según el botón que pulses.

```
function swapVisibility() {
    $("#btnFiltroAvanzado").css('display', 'none');
    $("#btnSimple").css('display', 'initial');
}
function classListadd() {
    $("#btnFiltroAvanzado").css('display', 'initial');
    $("#btnSimple").css('display', 'none');
}
```

```
<button id=btnFiltroAvanzado 
onclick= swapVisibility()>hola</button>

<button id=btnSimple
onclick=classListadd()>adios</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function swapVisibility(button) {
   if($(button).prop("id")=="btnSimple"){
      $(button).addClass("d-none")
      $("#btnFiltroAvanzado").removeClass("d-none")
   }else{
      $(button).addClass("d-none")
      $("#btnSimple").removeClass("d-none")
   }
}
```

```css
.d-none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnSimple"
onclick="swapVisibility(this)">Clickmeplis
</button>

<button id="btnFiltroAvanzado" class="d-none"
onclick="swapVisibility(this)">Clickme
</button>
```

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo con `jquery`, acá te dejo una de tantas posibilidades, ojala te sirva saludos. [Aca](https://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-addclass-removeclass-4705/) te dejo mas información acerca de los métodos utilizados en este fragmento de código

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".target" ).toggle()
```

.target es la clase de los elementos a ocultar mostrar.

Si necesitas mas control puedes usar .show() y .Hide() https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).